# User independent TEMP directory for powershell remote copy

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using `Copy-Item -FromSession` to copy a database backup to my local host. Actually `Copy-Item` has a "bug" where the remote directory has to be available on the target machine. My problem: on the remote machine I copy the DB backup to `$env:TEMP`. Depending on the given credentials I'm running under a different user than the one used on my local machine. Resulting from this the directory to copy the backup from doesn't exist on my machine. For example if the remote user is "Johnny" the backup is situated under "C:\Users\Johnny\AppData\Local\Temp". If I'm logged as "Jim" on my local machine, the `Copy-Item` cmdlet will break since there is no "C:\Users\Johnny\AppData\Local\Temp" on my local machine.

Can somebody give me a hint if there is a more or less "generic" temp folder available in Windows? Is it ok to user C:\Windows\temp for such an issue?

Comment: Any reason you aren't copying the backup to either, a share on you local machine or from a share on the remote machine? You only need to setup the share and permissions once and every copy from then on will be treated the same.

Comment: Of course a possible solution, but with `-FromSession` I don't have to setup any shares at all. So it would be great if can use the remote copy solution.

Comment: How about `C:\Users\Public\AppData\Local\Temp` since that is the profile setup for access for all accounts that have access to the machine?

Comment: Thats one of my problems, my Win10 machine doesn't have a `C:\Users\Public\AppData` folder. I also checked the hidden folders, nothing there.